# How can I use the ffmpeg command to reverse video?

Tags: command-line, video, android, ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFmpeg library in Android to reverse video. I can dump images from videos, but how can I reverse all images and make a new video?

I am using a library [from here](http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/) in my gradle. Library is `compile 'com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg:FFmpegAndroid:0.2.5'`. I can use some of the commands but not all. I'm using this command to dump images from video:

```
-i /storage/emulated/0/ffvid/frameCount.mp4 -an -qscale 1 /storage/emulated/0/ffimg/revi%06d.jpg
```

I can't use the commands `$ffmpeg` , `$sox` and `$cat`

I have unsuccessfully tried following these suggestions:

- [How can I reverse a video clip | Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214327/how-can-i-reverse-a-video-clip)
- [Reverse video clip with ffmpeg | blogspot](http://jiaxihu.blogspot.in/2012/05/reverse-video-clip-with-ffmpeg.html)

What else can I try?

Comment: Do you mean `$cat` or `cat`?

Comment: cat command i don't know which perfect i am android developer but i need help to make video in severe. and command use time i can't abale to add prefix in command as like `ffpmeg` ,`sox` and `cat`.

Comment: It is discouraged to crosspost the [same question](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17738/how-to-use-ffmpeg-command-for-reverse-video) to multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a crosspost

Comment: So are you running Ubuntu or Android then? And which version?

Comment: I am using third party library. and library base on FFMPEG.  https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW Are you on Video Production? I think it should be closed there (it's on-topic here and it was posted here first).

Comment: @kos AFAI understood he's on Android...

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐqɹW Ah I see, it has been crossposted on multiple sites (http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17738/how-to-use-ffmpeg-command-for-reverse-video).

Comment: see here http://video.stackexchange.com/a/17739

Answer (score 30):

It looks like it runs ffmpeg and so instead of this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -vf reverse reversed.mp4
```

and this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -vf reverse -af areverse reversed.mp4
```

Run this instead:

```
-i inputfile.mp4 -vf reverse reversed.mp4
```

and this:

```
-i inputfile.mp4 -vf reverse -af areverse reversed.mp4
```

https://video.stackexchange.com/a/17739

Thanks LordNeckbeard!

It looks like this only works for ffmpeg commands and so commands like cat won't work.

I didn't look at it too close but it looks like if you try to run `cat` you would really be running `ffmpeg cat` which does not exist.

You see, if you run `-i input.mkv -an -qscale 1 %06d.jpg` from a terminal, this does nothing but if you run `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -an -qscale 1 %06d.jpg` it does. This indicates that this application runs `ffmpeg` and allows you to add the option `-i input.mkv -an -qscale 1 %06d.jpg` to the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: yes you are right but i need to use that that for want i can do via above link that i give in my question

Comment: @RaviVGHL Okay, I see.  It looks like you are running the `ffmpeg` command and everything you run is only run after `ffmpeg` so commands like `cat` won't work. If you want to run `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -an -qscale 1 %06d.jpg` you should run this instead `-i input.mkv -an -qscale 1 %06d.jpg`

Comment: cat command not works as like that

Comment: @RaviVGHL Well, I didn't look at it too close but it looks like if you try to run `cat` you would really be running `ffmpeg cat` which does not exist. You see, if you run `-i input.mkv -an -qscale 1 %06d.jpg` from a terminal, this does nothing but if you run `ffmpeg -i input.mkv -an -qscale 1 %06d.jpg` it does. This indicates that this application runs ffmpeg and allows you to add the option `-i input.mkv -an -qscale 1 %06d.jpg` to the ffmpeg command.

Comment: you are right but can you give me correct way for reverse video and slow motion also.

Comment: @RaviVGHL I think this will help https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video That is for slow motion however, I don't know that it is possible to reverse video with ffmpeg.

Comment: @mchid See this [duplicate crosspost](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17738/how-to-use-ffmpeg-command-for-reverse-video) for one method (I've never tried it however).

Comment: @RaviVGHL See comment by LordNeckbeard. You should be able to run  `-i /storage/emulated/0/ffvid/frameCount.mp4 -vf reverse -af areverse reversed.mp4`

Comment: **Warning:** this method forces `ffmpeg` to load the _entire_ video into memory and unless you have a 10 second clip or 32 GB of RAM, it isn't going to work.

Comment: I only have 5GB RAM.

Comment: I just want to play a video using ffmpeg in android, can you guide me

Comment: @AbdulMuheet This is askubuntu and is the ubuntu stackexchange. This question is about developing for android on ubuntu and not about android. For questions about android, please ask your question on https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @AbdulMuheet I have not used `ffmpeg` on android. However, you would normally use the `ffplay` command to play the video instead of the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: If you run out of memory, you can add e.g. the `-ss 10 -t 5` options to only reverse a 5-second portion starting 10 seconds in. You could do that several times and then splice them together. @NathanOsman